# Is there a way to auto generate all the characters in a typeface?

Tags: macos, font

Looking for a way to generate all the available characters provided in a particular typeface so that I can then copy and paste them into a design program, like Illustrator, or a plaintext program like BBEdit.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what you will do with them after that? The tricky bit is checking whether the font has that glyph, rather than falling back onto another font.

Comment: Fonts often have many glyphs that may not be able to be copy/pasted, as they are not attached to unicode codepoints but generated by typographic processes.  But aside from that, have you tried doing this from the Repertoire option under View in Font Book?

Comment: Fontbook will show you all the glyphs in each font installed (like @Tom Gewecke posted just before me ;-), if you then print that to a PDF you have a document you can copy/paste those glyphs from into something else. Does that work for you? I believe there are a number of shareware font utilities that do exactly what you are looking for.